# Use values of variables 1,2,3 as condition to set the value of variable 4

Tags: r, if-statement

So I basically have a (badly designed) survey, with multiple item batteries where for each item, multiple replies are possible and therefore there are multiple variables per item which can be either 0 or 1 depending on whether that answer was clicked. There is also a "don't know" answer, which again, has its own variable.

Due to the optional nature of these answers some respondents who should've chosen the "don't know" category chose none at all, I want to rectify this (I know, questionable in terms of quality). I want to code an ifelse statement that recodes the dk variable, let's call it variable 4, to 1 if the previous variables 1,2 and 3 have the value 0 within one line/case in the dataset.

I have tried the following, sorry for the german variable names:

`ifelse(df_c$F4T1_SQ001_SQ001_pc_privat==0 & df_c$F4T1_SQ001_SQ002_pc_mathematik==0 & df_c$F4T1_SQ001_SQ003_pc_deutsch==0 & df_c$F4T1_SQ001_SQ004_pc_sachunterricht==0 & df_c$F4T1_SQ001_SQ005_pc_englisch==0 & df_c$F4T1_SQ001_SQ006_pc_sport==0 & df_c$F4T1_SQ001_SQ007_pc_ethik==0, df_c$F4T1_SQ001_SQ008_pc_nicht==1, df_c$F4T1_SQ001_SQ008_pc_nicht==0)`

sadly this only returned statements regarding the condition being TRUE or not and I am unsure if it actually properly checked for the condition. Any input would be appreciated, including easier ways to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this:

```r
if (!require("tidyverse")) { install.packages("tidyverse") }
library(tidyverse)
df_c %<>%
    mutate(F4T1_SQ001_SQ008_pc_nicht = ifelse(F4T1_SQ001_SQ001_pc_privat | 
                                              F4T1_SQ001_SQ002_pc_mathematik | 
                                              F4T1_SQ001_SQ007_pc_ethik, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I think I get what your code is trying to do but when trying to run it I get the error 

'Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `F4T1_SQ001_SQ008_pc_nicht = ifelse(...)`.
Caused by error in `ifelse()`:
! argument "yes" is missing, with no default'

which seems to be caused by the first bracket here 'ethik), 0, 1)' separating the conditions from the rest of the ifelse formula, is that correct?

Comment: You are right. I corrected that typo.

Comment: Thank you, I was unsure if it was a typo or in some way required for it to work with the mutate function, I'll report back on whether it worked as intended.

Comment: Added the remaining variables to the condition portion and it ran as well as the number of 1 values for F4T1_SQ001_SQ008_pc_nicht increasing, seems like it worked, thanks a lot!